# Firefox: nested div doesn't align properly

Tags: css, firefox

I have a button that looks fine in every browser except FF:

```
<button><div>Button Text</div></button>
```

The gist is that I have a background on the button & div so that the button can be scaled to any width.  In Firefox, the div is 1px lower than the button, and I'm not sure why.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/FgHV4/4/

Simplified code:

```html
<button><div>foo</div></button>

<style>
button {
    border      : 0px;
    background  : #CCC;
    height      : 29px;
    line-height : 29px;
    padding     : 0px;
}

div {
    background  : #AAA;
    height      : 29px;
    line-height : 29px;
    position    : relative;
    left        : 7px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can scale the <button> to any width or height. Why the extra <div>? I don't understand...

Comment: There's a background image in the real button, not just a color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it match (for example) Chrome, you need this:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/FgHV4/5/

On an unrelated note `div` [is not a valid child](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FFgHV4%2F5%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) of `button` (in HTML5). You should change it to a `span`.

Comment: accepted (Thanks!), but ___wtf???___.  Yeah, don't care about HTML validation.  Not a single browser will complain.

Comment: Relevant Firefox user agent CSS: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/forms.css#571